# How to always load a UIViewController in portrait mode even if the device is rotated horizontally in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I have UIViewController in portrait mode and when I go to another UIViewController and rotate device horizontally then go back to previous UIViewController it's view is all messed up. My application supports every orientation of device, I implemented methods:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

but I could not resolve this problem. How to load UIViewContoller always in portrait orientation regardless of device orientation, and orientation of previous loaded UIViewContoller? Thanks for your answers and help.

Comment: Try turning ShouldAutorotate to YES.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. :) In viewDidLoad I put this line of code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
```

and add methods:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}
```

It works fine.

Comment: no no I am not read your question fully , sorry for wrong answer